# How to handle Bootstrap3 modal popup message in Python selenium testing?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, automated-tests, python-unittest

I am using below code to handle popup or alert

```
alert = driver.switch_to_alert()
alert_text = alert.text
print alert_text
```

But for "**bootstrap modal**" "modal-body" -- How I have to handle, pls help me guys, give some **idea** to handle this issue

Comment: The modal popup is just elements in the DOM which you can find using the usual `driver.find_element_by...` API - e.g. searching for the class of the modal body, and then performing any actions etc.

Comment: Thanks, @Will Keelin It's working .... implicitly wait is not working here.. when I making web driver to wait for 2 to 3 seconds  ..that time only able to find expath